# Select a range of text using one of the built-in UNIX tools

Tags: awk, sed, grep

My target file is python module and looks like this:

```
def function_one(arg):
    """docstring"""

    code
    code
    code


def function_two(arg):
    """docstring"""

    code
    code
    code
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the body of `function_one` using either `awk`, `sed` or `grep`.

The way I want to approach this is to select a range of text between the function name and two blank lines (since every function definition ends with two blank lines).

What I've come up with so far is an `awk` command that selects text from the function name up until the first blank line:
`awk '/def function_one/,/^$/' module.py`.

However that only produces this text, since there's a blank line between my docstring and the function body:

```
def function_one(arg):
    """docstring"""
```

How should I go about defining a range starting with a string an ending with precisely **two** blank lines?

Comment: The absolutely best way to parse Python is to use Python itself. Examine the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^def[[:space:]]+function_one\(/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    if ( !NF && !pNF ) {
        prtBlock()
        block = ""
        inBlock = 0
    }
    else {
        block = block $0 ORS
        pNF = NF
    }
}
END { if (inBlock) prtBlock() }

function prtBlock() {
    sub(/\n+$/,"",block)
    print block
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
def function_one(arg):
    """docstring"""

    code
    code
    code
```

Answer (score 0):

how about - with GNU awk:

```
gawk -v RS='\n\n\n' '/function_one/' myFile
```

Comment: You don;t need the `$'...'` bash-ism with awk, just `RS='\n\n\n'` would be enough.

Comment: You could make this far more robust if you change `/function_one/` to `/^def\s+function_one\(/` btw.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and "def" as the record separator:

```
awk -v RS="def" '/function_one/ { print "def "$0 }' module.py
```

Comment: You should mention  that requires GNU awk for mult-char RS.

Comment: @PatRes I see you accepted this solution. Try it when function_one contains a comment like `This is definitely a problem` or when there's a function before function_one that calls function_one or.... It's always trivial to match the text you want to match and much harder to not match text you don't want to match,

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind having trailing empty line, you might do as follow, let `file.txt` content be:

```
def function_one(arg):
    """docstring"""

    code
    code
    code


def function_two(arg):
    """docstring"""

    code
    code
    code
```

then

```
awk '{curr=length($0);if(prev==0 && curr==0)exit;prev=curr;print}' file.txt
```

output:

```
def function_one(arg):
    """docstring"""

    code
    code
    code
```

Explanation: I use prev to store length of whole line, if prev line length and current line length are 0 then stop processing. For every line just print it.